# What is happening such I receive dangerouslySetInnerHTML warning and empty content using Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

**First-off, I do know I should not nest `<p>` tags.**

So I created a Next.js application and I have a component that sets rich text html as follows:

```
    <Typography
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: richText
      }}
    />
```

The react component `Typography` is just a `p` tag in the end so this could simply be written as:

```
    <p
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: richText
      }}
    />
```

So when the browser loads the page, my content does not show up and I am left with the console warning:

```
Warning: Prop 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' did not match. Server: "" Client: "<p>...</p>"
```

After a lengthy debugging session, during cleaning up, using the `<span>` instead of `<p>` was the solution

```
    <span
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: richText
      }}
    />
```

Nested p tags was a mistake, regardless, what is happening that makes Next.js not render this particular content resulting in the empty string `Server: ""`? Is Next.js just simply very sensitive to errors and warnings?

Comment: `Nested p tags was a mistake…` Thank you, solved my issue!

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same problem because in the `richtext` I was getting `<p>` tags too, so when I switched my wrapping tag from `<p>` to `<div>` that error disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I solved this using react `useState` and `useEffect` hooks. so it's not rendering in the server.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ParentComponent({ content }) {
   const [render, setRender] = useState(false);
   
   useEffect(() => {
      setRender(true);
   }, []);

   return <Typography dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: render && content }} />
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Next.js will de-nest invalid html on the server so

```
<p> 
  <p>
     hello world
  </p>
</p>
```

becomes

```
<p></p>
<p> hello world </p>
```

so the HTML structure no longer matches the client rendered html hence rehydration fails

Answer (score 1):

Material-UI have a prop called component. use component as `div`

```
<Typography {...other Typography Props} component="div" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: richText
  }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where `richText` is coming from. Is it possible that on the server-side render, `richText = ""`, and then you make some API request on the front-end that sets the value of richText?

Comment: No, that was my initial thought too but `richText` is not an empty string on the server side. I make the call in `getInitialProps` and I am 100% sure it is not an empty string.